# Problem with Jupyter Notebook after update

Tags: jupyter

need some help to understand what happened, after i update anaconda, my Jupyter Notebook away return me this error when I try to open a file:

[image]

Not matter what directory it in, it's always returns me this

I tryed to reinstall Python and other dependencies, tryed to reinstall PyPI too, but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

How did you reinstall python and dependencies?

If not already done, I would try this:

```
conda clean --all
conda update --all
conda install pandas
conda install jupyter
```

Comment: I already use this, i uninstal anaconda, and download it again, reinstal python on pc, and still with same problem. funny is the jupyter lab works, jupyter notebook not